# Finding the recurrence relation(with square roots)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I came across a very peculiar recurrence relation :

> $\sqrt {T(n)} = \sqrt {T(n-1)} + 2 \sqrt {T(n-2)}  $

And Initial Condition $T(0) = T(1)= 1$

Any helps on how to find it

Comment: Any information on initial conditions?  What if we define $S(n) = \sqrt{T(n)}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $A(n)=\sqrt{T(n)}$ and solve for A formula.

For example try to find in $A(n) = \lambda^{n}$ form.